# Need Help to adding new array into JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm making an file managing web page with nodejs and need some help.

I'm adding some informations into JSON object which recieved from DB.
the DB constains stage informations and I should link informations about stage files.

this is code for the function. Added comments into codes.

```
DBmodel.findOne({'key': 'server'}).exec(function (err, data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.stage.length; i++) {
        // this was successful. I added an array to check each files.
        data.stage[i].packFileNameArray = data.stage[i].packFileName.split("/");
        data.stage[i].packVersionArray = data.stage[i].packVersion.split("/");

        // this is a problem. I will add file information for each file.
        // I 
        for (var j = 0; j < data.stage[i].packFileNameArray.length; j++) {
            fs.stat(dirPath + data.stage[i].packFileNameArray[j], function (err, fileStat) {
                if (err) {
                    // this was first try. I thought the array will be automaticallt created.
                    data.stage[i].isExist[j] = 'NO';
                    data.stage[i].mTime[j] = '0';
                    data.stage[i].size[j] = '0';
                } else {
                    // this was second try. I tried push into each time.
                    data.stage[i].isExist.push('YES');
                    data.stage[i].mTime.push(fileStat.mTime);
                    data.stage[i].size.push(fileStat.size);
                }
                console.log(data.stage[i].isExist[j]);
                console.log(data.stage[i].mTime[j]);
                console.log(data.stage[i].size[j]);
            });
        }

    }

    });
```

I want to know how I can add additional informations as an array into the JSON object.

Thank you.

Comment: There are no JSON objects. There are objects, and there is JSON (a string formatted according to certain rules). What do you want to add, and to what? What do you want as your result?

Comment: can you post your model schema and or could you post what your original JSON looks like before and what you WANT it to look like after?

Answer (score 0):

```
data.stage[i].push({ isExist: 'Yes'});
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the arrays (as the do not seem to exist) before you can push data into them:

```
DBmodel.findOne({'key': 'server'}).exec(function (err, data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.stage.length; i++) {
    // this was successful. I added an array to check each files.
    data.stage[i].packFileNameArray = data.stage[i].packFileName.split("/");
    data.stage[i].packVersionArray = data.stage[i].packVersion.split("/");

    data.stage[i].isExist = [];
    data.stage[i].mTime = [];
    data.stage[i].size = [];
    //...
```